# If statement in batch scripting

Tags: windows, batch-file

What I am trying to do is to check if the variable %%c contains a "More" if that is the case insted of a more there should be a "not granted"

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq skip=10 tokens=1,5,9 delims= " %%a in ("log.txt") do (
    if %%c == "more"(
    set "status" ="Not granted"     
    )
    set "date=%%a"
    set "type=%%b"
    set "status=%%c"
    echo type: !type!
    echo status: !status!
    echo date: !date!
    echo.
)>>Test.txt
pause
```

Comment: contains or is equal to "more". Because in your code you are checking for equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoru basic questin is: "Does a variable contain a certain string"

In your case (using a `for` variable), I would use:

```
echo %%c|find "more">nul && set "status=Not granted"
```

print the string, pipe it to `find` (redirecting the ouptut to NUL) and if `find` was successful, then do something

Comment: yes u are 100% right about that is there a specific position where I should put this line ? and btw for example this only happens if the variable contains  a more ?

Comment: it replaces your `if %%c == "more" (set "status" ="Not granted")`. The `set` command is only executed, if `%%c` contains "more" (or "amore" or "moreno" or ... If you are sure, there is reliably a space before and after it, use `find " more "` )

Comment: ... Or use word boundaries with `findstr /i "\<more\>"`